# Проблема при создании комментариев к фотографиям с помощью vk java api

Tags: java, vkontakte-api

Добрый день.
Есть необходимость добавлять комментарии к фото вк с помощью vk java sdk.
Фото загружаются без проблем, альбомы создаются. Проблема только с комментариями.

Необходимо комментировать исключительно фото, добавленные в альбомы пользователя, на чей аккаунт получен токен.
При получении доступа указаны в качестве scope `friends,photos,offline,groups,notes`.

Для создания комментария вызывается такой код:

```
vkApiClient.photos().createComment(actor, photoId).message(text).execute();
```

На выходе ошибка доступа

> SEVERE: API error
>   com.vk.api.sdk.exceptions.ApiAccessException: Access denied (15): Access denied: no access to call this method

Спасибо.

Comment: поскольку возвращается ошибка 15 а не 7, значит проблема не в токене, а в правах доступа к комментированию фотографии.

Comment: ну я тоже так подумал. в оф.документации вк для метода photos().createComment написано , что требуются права доступа: photos. А права доступа, насколько я понимаю, указываются при получении токена в параметре scope. Ну у меня указано несколько параметров, в т.ч. photos. Самое интересное, что фото грузятся и даже описание к ним создается. А попытка напсать коммент кидает ошибку.

Comment: это ошибка не прав доступа токена, а прав пользователя комментировать конкретную фотографию.

Comment: так я сам свою комментирую...

Comment: сама фотография публикуется? через сайт её видно? можно ли добавить комментарий к ней через сайт?

Comment: да, фото публикуется, на сайте ее видно. с сайта я комментарий добавляю без проблем